# discord.js タイマー機能の試験中に「チャンネルが存在しない」エラーが発生

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

以下のプログラムにおいて、「スラッシュコマンドのオプションで0d0h0m0sの形でタイマーの時間を指定し、チャンネルIDの指定があればそのIDのチャンネルで、なければコマンドを実行したチャンネルでメッセージを送信する」という動作を想定していたのですが、「Channel (チャンネルID) not found or not a text channel.」とログに表示されました。

```
} else {
  console.error(`Channel ${channelId} not found or not a text channel.`);
}
```

スラッシュコマンドのオプションで指定した場合もオプションで指定せず実行した場合も同じエラーが発生します。
チャンネルそのものは存在しますし、権限も十分にありますがエラーが発生します。

なおJSONファイルの中身は `{}` となっていますが、開発環境の都合で更新が遅れている可能性もあります。前のプログラムでBOT起動直後、つまりスラッシュコマンドを実行していない場合でも同じエラーが発生していたので、JSONファイルの中身を  `{}` にあらためて書き換えて試しましたが、エラーは解消しませんでした。

**現状のコード:**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
//const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
 const {
     Client,
     GatewayIntentBits: {
         Guilds,
         GuildMessages,
         MessageContent
     },
     Collection,
     Events,
     GatewayIntentBits,
     Partials
 } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  'intents': [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, 
            GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, 
            GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions, 
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent], 
  'partials': [Partials.User, 
             Partials.Channel, 
             Partials.GuildMember, 
             Partials.Message, 
             Partials.Reaction] 
});


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('timer')
        .setDescription('タイマー')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('time')
                .setDescription('タイマーの時間を設定します（例: 1d2h3m4s）')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addChannelOption(option =>
            option.setName('channel')
                .setDescription('通知を送るチャンネルのIDを入力します')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const { options, channel } = interaction;

        const timeString = options.getString('time');
        const timeInSeconds = convertTimeStringToSeconds(timeString);

        if (timeInSeconds === null) {
            return interaction.reply('Invalid time format. Please use the format "0d0h0m0s".');
        }

        const channelId = options.getChannel('channel')?.id || channel.id;

        // Save timer data to JSON file
        const timerData = { endTime: Date.now() + (timeInSeconds * 1000), channelId };
        fs.writeFileSync('timers.json', JSON.stringify(timerData));

        await interaction.reply(`Timer set for ${timeString}. Will notify in specified time.`);

        // Notify when timer is up
        const foundChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
        if (foundChannel && foundChannel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT') {
            foundChannel.send('Timer is up!');
        } else {
            console.error(`Channel ${channelId} not found or not a text channel.`);
        }
    }
};

function convertTimeStringToSeconds(timeString) {
    const regex = /(\d+)d(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s/;
    const match = timeString.match(regex);

    if (!match) {
        return null; // Invalid time format
    }

    const days = parseInt(match[1]) || 0;
    const hours = parseInt(match[2]) || 0;
    const minutes = parseInt(match[3]) || 0;
    const seconds = parseInt(match[4]) || 0;

    return (days * 24 * 60 * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
}
```

Comment: 実際にエラーが起こっている箇所とは関係ないコードが多すぎるように見えます。問題点を切り分けるため、問題となっている箇所以外を取り除いて単体でエラーになるかどうかを確かめてください。そしてその部分だけのコードにしてみてください。参考: [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)